# What's the mechanism of MacBook's (quiet, low power consumption) sleep/hibernate?

Tags: linux, windows, sleep, macbook, hibernate

Is MacBook's sleep/hibernation a pure hardware implementation or it's software relevant?

Can Linux/Windows on MacBook sleep/hibernate like OS X?

Can non-MacBook laptops sleep/hibernate like MacBook?

related to: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35336/what-happens-when-i-close-the-lid-on-my-macbook-pro-running-os-x

Answer (score 1):

"Sleep" requires some hardware assistance (system is kept running in a very low-power mode). Hibernate doesn't:  the system state is saved to disk and the system is completely switched off; on power-up the boot process recovers the previous state.

Non-Apple laptops have been able to sleep/hibernate for about as long as Apple products (if not before...). This is a very standard feature.

Comment: From my experience, during sleep, Dell/Thinkpad with SSD + Windows consumes a lot more battery power than MacBook + OS X, and perceptibly louder.

Comment: In my experience, my Thinkpad-cum-Ubuntu can sleep for about three days, and be completely silent when so. MacBooks use the same chips (CPU and "bridges") than ordinary PCs.